# Pass multiple select options text to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form in which there are several select boxes, some of which are multiple select. Thus far, I am able to pass the text value from each select box to a textarea; however, I'm unable to pass more than one option from the multiple select box. Can anyone help here? Meaning, I'd like to pass all the selected text in the multiple select boxes, not just the first item among the selections.

My code keeps returning 'undefined'. In searching these forums, it seems that using the jQuery 'option:selected' modifier should return the text of all the selected items.

```
function writeText(){
// get assign the values from each text input
var myCAPtext = document.getElementById('CAPoutput');

// assign multiple text values
var select_1 = $("#box1 option:selected").text();

var  CAPtext = select_1.value+"\n\n";
  myCAPtext.value = CAPtext;
  }
```

HTML

```
<select id="box1" multiple>
<option></option>
<option>first text</option>
<option>second text</option>
<option>third text</option>
<option>fouth text</option>
</select>

<input value="Write" onclick="writeText()" type="button"> <br>

<textarea id="CAPoutput">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text` returns a string, String object doesn't have `value` property, use jQuery `val` method, it returns an array of values for multiple select element, then you can use `join` method of the array object for joining the array's elements:

```
var select_1 = $("#box1").val();
var CAPtext = select_1.join("\n\n");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZCTRC/

In case that you want to say goodbye to `onclick` attributes:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
    var myCAPtext = document.getElementById('CAPoutput');
    myCAPtext.value = $("#box1").val().join("\n\n");
})
```

Comment: +1, seems not many people notice that `val()` returns an array for multiple.

Comment: Hi, that worked beautifully. Thanks for giving a detailed explanation of the solution. That really helps coding newbies like me to get better. Out of curiosity, could I use the same syntax structure to pass string values to my text box, if I added checkboxes or text inputs to my form?

Comment: @user1837608 Hi, you are welcome, yes, but for those elements `val` returns a `string` so you cannot use `join` method.

Comment: One more question, if you don't mind. As I'm finishing my form, I realize that there are some select elements that should be made optional. How best can I include these "optional" select items, but ignore them if they are not desired? I was thinking to tie it somehow to a checkbox that alerts the write function to include any selectbox after a checked checkbox? Is there something easier already built within jQuery?